# Core Data object property access inside Block crash

Tags: ios, core-data, objective-c-blocks

### EDIT

OK, I think I figured it out.

My overall flow of operation was like this:

```
-(void)submitRegistration
{    
    //[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] drupalLogin];

    [self validateFields];

    if(fieldsValid)
    {
        [self createBike];

        // save member node will save bike node too if successful
        // bike node will not be saved if member node did not save successful
        [self saveMemberNode];

        // save the updated member node and bike node to Core Data
        [self saveLocalRegistration]; 
        // *** ABOVE LINE GETS EXECUTED BEFORE ASYNC REQUEST FINISHES ***
    }
}
```

My "[self saveLocalRegistration];" code had executed before the Asynchronous request "Block" had finish executing, causing it to crash.

The "saveLocalRegistration" method calls [managedObjectContext save:&error];

### Original Question

Just took my first dive into Core Data.

In my app, one of the thing I am trying to do is send some data to a Drupal server.

I have narrowed down the problem to this:

```
// *** *** *** 
// doesn't crash here
// *** *** ***
NSLog(@"bike.brand = %@", bike.brand);
NSLog(@"bike.model = %@", bike.model);
NSLog(@"bike.features = %@", bike.features);

// save new member node to Drupal
[DIOSNode nodeSave:memberData success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) 
 {
     NSLog(@"Node saved!");
     NSDictionary *serverNodeData = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

     NSLog(@"Server node details = %@", serverNodeData);

     // set the member's memberId to the newly created Drupal member node's nodeId
     member.memberId = [NSNumber numberWithLong:[[serverNodeData valueForKey:@"nid"] longLongValue]];

     // *** *** ***
     // accessing bike properties here inside this objective c "Block" crashes app
     // somehow the above line "member.memberId = .... " doesn't crash despite both being Core Data entities
     // *** *** ***
     NSLog(@"bike.brand = %@", bike.brand); // <--- CRASH HERE ***
     NSLog(@"bike.model = %@", bike.model);
     NSLog(@"bike.features = %@", bike.features);

     //bike.ownerId = member.memberId;

     // save bike node with member id
     [self saveBikeNode];
 } 
           failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) 
 {
     NSLog(@"Failed to save node, error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
 }];
```

As you can see from the above source code, the first block of NSLogs doesn't crash the app but inside the objective c "Block", the same block of NSLogs crashes the app.

Note: the "[DIOSNode nodeSave:memberData success:...." Objective C block is an Asynchronous request I believe. Don't know if this could be a multi threading issue or not.

bike.brand, bike.model and bike.features are "String" data types.

Comment: Don't edit the question - add your own answer and accept it. (You have to wait a while before you can accept it)

Answer (score 0):

declare this outside the block and use it inside ur block instead of 'self'

```
__block <classname> *blocksafeSelf = self;
```

Comment: How does that prevent the crash? The crash is happening at the NSLog(), not at the [self saveBikeNode];

Answer (score 0):

I could confirm that by looking at the state of the debugger just before the crash, but my understanding is that you are accessing a managed object from a thread which it doesn't belong to.

You must schedule the success block on the managed object context designed queue (performBlock and performBlockAndWait).